# How to add a custom variable to a form_widget

Tags: symfony, twig

I am currently creating a simple register form with the Symfony2 form component. 
I want to add a span to be able to change the glyphicon/font-awesome. How can I add a "custom" variable that would allow me to do something like :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {% if icon %}
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="{{ icon }}"></span></span>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}

<div class="input-group">
    {{ form_widget(register.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}, 'icon' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'}}) }}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't proper understand your scenario: you can access the form object via form.vars.value  as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template) or implement the buildView method as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html#adding-the-extension-business-logic). Hope this help